# Как на JS кликнуть по ссылке?

Tags: javascript

Привет, есть такая ссылка в ВК.

```
<a class="ui_actions_menu_item" role="link" tabindex="0" onclick="wall.deletePost(this, '395737740_8', 'de6d40183f2070c87e');"></a>
```

У меня в переменной есть этот идентификатор `395737740_8`  как используя этот идентификатор кликнуть по этой ссылки.  Дело в том что таких ссылок много у меня на странице и отобрать нужную мне ссылку я могу только по этой строчке `395737740_8` Помогите решить задачу. решение нужно именно на JavaScript.

Comment: `wall.deletePost(this, '395737740_8', 'de6d40183f2070c87e')` подойдёт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let id = '395737740_8';

document.querySelectorAll('.ui_actions_menu_item').forEach(a => a.onclick.toString().includes(`${id}`) ? a.classList.add('yep') : null);
```

```css
.yep{
  background: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<a class="ui_actions_menu_item" role="link" tabindex="0" onclick="wall.deletePost(this, '325737740_8', 'de6d40183f2070c87e');">Не то</a><br />
<a class="ui_actions_menu_item" role="link" tabindex="0" onclick="wall.deletePost(this, '335737740_8', 'de6d40183f2070c87e');">Опять не то</a><br />
<a class="ui_actions_menu_item" role="link" tabindex="0" onclick="wall.deletePost(this, '395737740_8', 'de6d40183f2070c87e');">Да, это я!</a><br />
<a class="ui_actions_menu_item" role="link" tabindex="0" onclick="wall.deletePost(this, '345737740_8', 'de6d40183f2070c87e');">Не нужно это</a>
```

Comment: нужно слегка подправить: если будет значение `395737740_88`, то оно тоже выделится

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, есть такое. Если генерация будет только в `'`, то можно как у Вас сделать.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');


function getLinkByClickStr(searchStr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {    
      var clickAttr = links[i].getAttribute("onclick");
      if (clickAttr.indexOf("'"+searchStr+"'") != -1) {
        links[i].click();        
        return;
      }        
  }
}

getLinkByClickStr('395737740_8');
```

```html
<a class="ui_actions_menu_item" role="link" tabindex="0" onclick="wall.deletePost(this, '395737740_88', 'de6d40183f2070c87e');">test</a>
<a class="ui_actions_menu_item" role="link" tabindex="0" onclick="wall.deletePost(this, '395737740_8', 'de6d40183f2070c87e');">test</a>
<a class="ui_actions_menu_item" role="link" tabindex="0" onclick="wall.deletePost(this, '3957232337740_8', 'de6d40183f2070c87e');">test</a>
```